# Using C# to access local database without DataObjects

Tags: c#, webforms, mdf

I want to run queries on the local database using C# and not the DataObjects, however, I'm finding incredibly little resources on how to connect/query (select/input) data. Is there a newbie-friendly resource on how to approach this? I found some resources using C#, but all are about DataObjects.

Comment: I think you may have searched for the wrong thing. Do not mention DataObjects in the search - try 'C# localdb'. With the 'mdf' tag, I assume you are using SQL Server or LocalDb (works similarly for developers). You would normally use ADO.NET/SqlClient normally, to access the database.

Comment: C# localdb gives me about the same results as previous searches. ADO.NET/SqlClient look promising I need to find out how to use it with the local db.

Comment: Simply create a Connection to the database with a ConnectionString, then create a Command (an SQL statement to execute) using the Connection, the grab the results into a DataSet/DataTable/TableAdapter or other structure to manipulate it afterwards.

Comment: You just need a `DataTable` from `System.Data`, and `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` from `System.Data.SqlClient` for the SQL Server stuff.